# Android Studio Databinding setVM not exist

Tags: android, android-databinding

I have a problem with the databinding on a fragment.

My Code:

```
Context context= getActivity();
FragmentWeatherViewPagerSlide01Binding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_weather_view_pager_slide01, container, false);
View rootView = binding.getRoot();
WeatherMainViewModel weatherMainViewModel= new WeatherMainViewModel(context);
binding.setVM(weatherMainViewModel);
```

in the xml:

```
 <data>
    <variable
        name="vm"
        type="ch.testing.test.views.weather.WeatherMainViewModel"/>
</data>
```

Android Studio does not know the setVM method. 
Why? did I forgot something?

Comment: `setVM` should be `setVm`

Comment: thx Blackbelt :-)